# Either its possible to get and show a value from front end in selenium Java. If so, then how I can do this

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, selenium2

I am testing a website and I need to perform some action on the basis of Price. It is showing price in Remaining Budget. I want to check the remaining budget and then on the basis of it want to perform action. [image]

You can see in pic about it.
Kindly share your experience about this.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can get values in form of String after that you can use them as you want.
like this -

```
String price = driver.findElement(By.xpath("your-xpth-of-selected-value")).getText();
```

Now this string value you can use as you need.

Comment: I have tried your solution and its working for me. But one things that its storing value in string and I want to use that value in if condition How I can use it.

Comment: Was running if(price.equals("xxxxx") problematic?

Comment: I am trying as if (Price >= some vale here)

Comment: then convert your string into integer like this - `int result = Integer.parseInt(price);`

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in above comment by Joao, you can get the text by

```
String price = driver.findElement(By.xpath("your-xpth-of-selected-value")).getText();
```

If you expect only integers in price, then you can do:

```
Integer.valueOf(price);
```

If you expect floats too, you can do :

```
Float.parseFloat(price);
```

HTH!

Comment: Now the issue is that its showing out put as " $24.00 ". I have to use this value in If condition or in For loop as the value is a mix of int, float and string how I can use it ?